# Drastic difference in GCC and Clang code performance

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, clang++

community. I have this piece of code that finds closest pair of points in Euclidean 3D space. This question is neither about the algorithm nor its implementation or whatever. The problem is that it runs **significantly** slower when compiled with GCC rather than Clang. Most confusingly, it has comparable execution time on random samples and like 100 times slower on some specific one. 
I suspect there can be a bug in GCC as I cannot think of any other option.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <complex>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <queue>

static std::mt19937 mmtw(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
int64_t rng(int64_t x, int64_t y) {
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<int64_t> d;
  return d(mmtw) % (y - x + 1) + x;
}

constexpr static int MAXN = 1e5 + 10;

void solve(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out);

void generate(std::ostream &out) {
  constexpr int N = 1e5;
  out << N << '\n';
  int MIN = -1e6;
  int MAX = 1e6;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    out << 0 << ' ';
    out << i << ' ';
    out << (i + 1) * int(1e4) << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {

  freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::cin.tie(nullptr);
  std::cout.tie(nullptr);
  std::cerr.tie(nullptr);

  std::ofstream fout("input.txt");
  generate(fout);
  fout.close();

  solve(std::cin, std::cout);

  return 0;
}

struct point_t {
  int32_t x, y, z;
  int id;
  point_t() = default;
  point_t(int32_t x, int32_t y, int32_t z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
  point_t operator +(const point_t &rhs) const {
    return point_t(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y, z + rhs.z);
  }
  point_t operator -(const point_t &rhs) const {
    return point_t(x - rhs.x, y - rhs.y, z - rhs.z);
  }
  int64_t abs2() const {
    return 1LL * x * x + 1LL * y * y + 1LL * z * z;
  }
};

std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &in, point_t &pt) {
  return in >> pt.x >> pt.y >> pt.z;
}

inline bool cmp_x(const point_t &lhs, const point_t &rhs) {
  return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}

inline bool cmp_y(const point_t &lhs, const point_t &rhs) {
  return lhs.y < rhs.y;
}

inline bool cmp_z(const point_t &lhs, const point_t &rhs) {
  return lhs.z < rhs.z;
}

struct pair_t {
  int64_t distance_sq;
  point_t a {}, b {};
  pair_t() : distance_sq(std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()) {};
  pair_t(const point_t &a, const point_t &b) : distance_sq((a - b).abs2()), a(a), b(b) {}
  bool operator<(const pair_t &rhs) const {
    return distance_sq < rhs.distance_sq;
  }
};

template <typename T> inline T sqr(T arg) { return arg * arg; }

point_t pts[MAXN];

static pair_t ans = pair_t();

void recur_2D(point_t pts[], int size, int64_t threshold_sq) {
  if (size <= 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) {
        ans = std::min(ans, pair_t(pts[i], pts[j]));
      }
    }
    std::sort(pts, pts + size, cmp_y);
    return;
  }
  int mid = size / 2;
  int midx = pts[mid].x;
  recur_2D(pts, mid, threshold_sq);
  recur_2D(pts + mid, size - mid, threshold_sq);

  static point_t buffer[MAXN];
  std::merge(pts, pts + mid, pts + mid, pts + size, buffer, cmp_y);
  std::copy(buffer, buffer + size, pts);

  int buff_sz = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (sqr(pts[i].x - midx) >= threshold_sq) {
      continue;
    }
    int64_t x_sqr = sqr(pts[i].x - midx);
    for (int j = buff_sz - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
      if (sqr(pts[i].y - buffer[j].y) + x_sqr >= threshold_sq) {
        break;
      }
      ans = std::min(ans, pair_t(pts[i], buffer[j]));
    }
    buffer[buff_sz++] = pts[i];
  }
}

void recur_3D(point_t pts[], int size) {
  if (size <= 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) {
        ans = std::min(ans, pair_t(pts[i], pts[j]));
      }
    }
    std::sort(pts, pts + size, cmp_x);
    return;
  }

  int mid = size / 2;
  int midz = pts[mid].z;

  recur_3D(pts, mid);
  recur_3D(pts + mid, size - mid);

  static point_t buffer[MAXN];
  std::merge(pts, pts + mid, pts + mid, pts + size, buffer, cmp_x);
  std::copy(buffer, buffer + size, pts);

  int buff_sz = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (sqr(pts[i].z - midz) >= ans.distance_sq) {
      continue;
    }
    buffer[buff_sz++] = pts[i];
  }
  recur_2D(buffer, buff_sz, ans.distance_sq);
}

void solve(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {

  clock_t start = clock();

  int num_of_points;
  in >> num_of_points;

  for (int i = 0; i < num_of_points; ++i) {
    in >> pts[i];
    pts[i].id = i + 1;
  }

  std::sort(pts, pts + num_of_points, cmp_z);
  recur_3D(pts, num_of_points);
  out << ans.distance_sq << '\n';
  out << 1.0 * (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s.\n";
}
```

Link to this code: https://code.re/2yfPzjkD

It generates the sample that makes the code very slow and then measures algorithm execution time.

I compile with

`g++ -DLOCAL -std=c++1z -O3 -Wno-everything main.cpp`

and with

`clang++ -DLOCAL -std=c++1z -O3 -Wno-everything main.cpp`

and run 
`./main` while having `input.txt` in the same directory.

The Clang-copiled binary runs in `0.053798 s.` while the GCC one in `12.4276 s.` . These numbers are from program's output, you can see that function `solve`.

I have also verified the difference on https://wandbox.org/ on different compiler versions.
https://wandbox.org/permlink/YFEEWSKyos2dQf32 -- clang
https://wandbox.org/permlink/XctarNHvd3I1B0x8 -- gcc

Note, I compressed input and thus had to change reading in `solve` a bit.

On my local machine I have these compilers.

`clang++ --version
clang version 7.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)`

`g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20180831`

It feels like I run GCC code without compiler optimizations. What can be the reason?

**UPD.**

Also, there is a version that calls `std::sort` only once in the very beginning.
https://wandbox.org/permlink/i9Kd3GdewxSRwXsM

I have also tried to compile Clang with `-stdlib=libstdc++`, shuffling data and think that different implementations of `std::sort` are not cause.

Comment: You could consider asking on  [gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/). BTW milliseconds are too short for benchmarking code, you should make a run which lasts more than half a second.

Comment: Please [edit] your code into the Q.  If you link dies the Q becomes unanswerable.

Comment: If you remove line 137 at https://wandbox.org/permlink/2MRwzb3yoiTZ8FTV , then the loop has no effect and is eliminated by any reasonable compiler. So it does not necessarily mean that this line is the culprit.

Comment: With such a high MAXN = 1e5 + 10, your automatic variable point_t pts[MAXN] is approx sizeof(point_t)*1e5 = 15Mb which is a **huge** stack storage. I do not know if it is the source of the problem but in all cases it is not a good practice (risks of stackoverflow...). Maybe try your code allocating memory on the heap (std::unique_ptr<point_t>(new point_t[MAXN]) to see the impact on the performance

Comment: @PicaudVincent `pts` is not an _automatic variable_. It is a _global variable (array)_ and therefore it is not stored in stack.

Comment: @DanielLangr opss, sorry I read the code to fast, yes it is not in a function body, you are right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simply *undefined behavior*. Your code has undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow at:

```
template <typename T> inline T sqr(T arg) { return arg * arg; }
```

You can replace that with:

```
template <typename T>
inline T sqr(T arg)
{
    assert(double(arg)*arg <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    assert(double(arg)*arg >= std::numeric_limits<T>::min());
    return arg * arg;
}
```

and catch the error in a debugger. It fails with `arg=-60000` called from `recur_3D` on the line:

```
if (sqr(pts[i].z - midz) >= ans.distance_sq) {
```

this happens with `pts[i] = {x = 0, y = 0, z = 10000, id = 1}` and `midz=70000`.

Because this is undefiend behavior, all bets are off. Different compiles utilize the assumption that "*undefined behavior never happens*" in different ways. This is why clang and gcc perform differently, and it is pure "luck".

Consider using [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) to catch these errors. I don't have it on my clang installation, but `clang++ -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow` should do the trick.

Fixing this function gives a comparable speed for both clang and gcc.